# Can I have a Jekyll collection that uses a date in its filename?

Tags: jekyll

I need to build a Jekyll collection – `events` – that has a title, a date, and a few other front matter variables:

```
---
title: Tournament
date: 2018-03-09 00:00:00
date_end: 2018-03-01 20:00:00
description: A big tournament is coming.
---
```

My collection is configured as:

```
collections:
  events:
    output: true
```

I want these to exist in the `_events` folder like

```
- 2018-03-09-tournament.md
```

and to be output in `_site` like:

```
- /event/2018-03-09-tournament/index.html
```

I've tried many combinations of things on the `permalink` attribute in `_config.yml`, but am unable to get my event to render if it includes a date in the filename.

Is this possible? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure [permalink](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/) like this :

```
collections:
  events:
    output: true
    future: true
    permalink: "/event/:year-:month-:day-:name/index:output_ext"
```

Comment: This results in no events being generated. In this instance, I've named the file `_events/2018-03-09-tournament.md`. When I remove the date from the filename, it generates as `_site/event/2018-03-06-tournament/index.html` (notice it uses today's date).

Comment: By default, posts or collection docs are not published if they have a date in the future. To see in the future, set `future: true` in your **_config.yml** file.